# What am I misunderstanding about char**?

Tags: c, pointers, char

I'm working on some homework for a computer science class and the last part of a rather tedious assignment is to write a function that can reverse sentences. The function prototype provided by the professor looks like this:

```
int reverseSentence(char** sentence, char **
                newsentence, int maxWords)
```

...where sentence is the original sentence, newsentence is where we're supposed to dump the reversed sentence, and maxWords is the number of words in the original sentence. I wrote my function like this...

```
int reverseSentence(char** sentence, char **
                newsentance, int maxWords)
{

    int i = maxWords;
    int x = 0;
    while(i > 0){
        newsentance[x] = sentence[i];
        x++;
        i--;
    }

    return maxWords;
}
```

However, the loop seems to be going on forever. Also, I seem to have a misunderstanding about how to make use of `char**`. I thought it was just an array of strings, like `char[words][characters]`. But I'm getting warnings about passing in an array of words to the function in that form. I'm not asking for anyone to do the homework for me, just to clear up what I'm missing about how to use `char**`.

Any help is appreciated. Thank you.

P.S - This is how I tried testing my code:

```
char sentence[3][4] = {"Hi\n", "my\n", "fri\n"};
char newsentence[3][4];
reverseSentence(sentence, newsentence, 3);
```

Comment: The loop should terminate assuming the code does not crash (i.e. the passed-in variables have reasonable values).  What value do you pass in for maxWords?

Comment: This is how I tried testing the code in my main: (updated in original question after P.S.)

Comment: It is sentence, not sentance :)

Answer (score 4):

As indicated in your comment, the code

```
char sentence[3][4] = {"Hi\n", "my\n", "fri\n"};
```

is valid but isn't compatible with a `char **`. Instead, it should be:

```
char *sentence[3] = {"Hi\n", "my\n", "fri\n"};
```

The first one is laid out in memory like this, characters packed into one block, three groups of four characters each:

```
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
| H | i | \n| \0| m | y | \n| \0| f | r | i | \n|
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
```

Note that the final entry does *not* have a trailing NUL (`\0`), because there is no room in the 4 characters available in the array.

The second declaration (what you want) is an array of three pointers to NUL-terminated strings:

```
+---------------+---------------+---------------+
|    char *     |    char *     |    char *     |
+---------------+---------------+---------------+
       |               |               |
       |               |               |    +---+---+---+---+---+
       |               |               +--> | f | r | i | \n| \0|
       |               |                    +---+---+---+---+---+
       |               |    +---+---+---+---+
       |               +--> | m | y | \n| \0|
       |                    +---+---+---+---+
       |    +---+---+---+---+
       +--> | H | i | \n| \0|
            +---+---+---+---+
```

Comment: And how should I allocate space for newsentence? I'm getting EXC_BAD_ACCESS now.

Comment: By referring to the above diagram, you will need to allocate space for the array of pointers (same length as `sentence`), and then make the pointers in `newsentence` point to the same words as in `sentence`, just in the reverse order. So `newsentence = malloc(maxWords * sizeof(char *));`

Comment: Ahh I see, so the purpose of doing it this way is so that I don't duplicate the original words in memory - just point to them in reverse order, is that correct?

Comment: @AnthonyFrizalone: Yes, that's exactly right. There are many possible ways to write the function "reverse the words in a sentence", and it sounds like this is the one the exercise is looking for.

Comment: @AnthonyFrizalone It's more than that... what you were doing before wasn't duplicating words at all. To be clear, C doesn't automatically copy strings for you when you assign them to some other `char *`. There's a reason why `strcpy()` exists... This might confuse you because when you declare variables C does "create memory" for you.

Comment: OK I think I'm starting to understand. So, then, is my function implementation correct? E.g. will it work if the variables being passed in are initialized correctly? Actually I'm thinking it's not correct

Comment: @AnthonyFrizalone: Your function is nearly correct. Pay attention to the array indexes, because you've got an off-by-one error.

Comment: The declaration `char sentence[3][4] = {"Hi\n", "my\n", "fri\n"};` is valid, `sentence` is an array of 3 `char[4]`, the constituent `char[4]` are initialized with the string literals. It's equivalent to `char sentence[3][4] = {{'H','i','\n','\0'}, {'m','y','\n','\0'}, {'f','r','i','\n'}};` The problem with that is semantic, the last one isn't 0-terminated, so passing `sentence[2]` to something that expects a (pointer to) 0-terminated `char[]` causes undefined behaviour.

Comment: Ah I was wondering how the compiler would deal with not having space for a null terminator. I haven't actually written C in a while...

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure why it's looping forever... but a few things to note:

1. You start with `i = maxWords`... this seems wrong. Arrays are indexed from 0, so what happens if you set `i = maxWords`?
2. Naming is a bit weird. First you have a typo in `newsentance`. Second you call it `maxWords` but it should be more like `numWords`, right?
3. If your understanding of `char*` is that it's an "array of strings, like char[words][characters]" then there is a huge huge gap between how you think about C types and how it actually exists (the short summary is that types/memory are one of the most important, fundamental, and *confusing* parts of C). Do you have a textbook to read about how types are represented in C? I'm not sure you even need to know it for this assignment... working naively might be intended.

**Edit** Oh dear. Does your declaration of the original sentence even compile? I'm not really sure how. You probably want to read about pointers again...

Comment: It could be called `maxWords` because a troll professors wants them to check for NULL and not exceed `maxWords` at the same time.

Comment: I agree with everything you said - my professor is responsible for the naming of maxWords and the typo - yes, it's retarded, but I dont wanna lose points for not naming things as she has. I have no textbook on the matter... I understand how pointers work. If I'm not mistaken, char* is a pointer to the first char in an array of characters which together create a string, correct? It's char** that I believe I don't understand. It seems it would be a pointer to a pointer to a char... But I'm not sure how that can be expanded to point to a sentence..

Comment: OK I think I'm starting to understand. So, then, is my function implementation correct? E.g. will it work if the variables being passed in are initialized correctly?

Comment: If you add the two lines of code Greg wrote and you modify some indexing issues you're done. 

But you've completely avoided learning about C memory/pointers (it sounds like you think you did, but there's really a big difference between looking at diagrams and understanding them vs. knowing the hundreds of nuances which turn out to be important for really basic stuff) and I think you're missing the point... maybe I'm being a pedantic arse though

Comment: I have a basic understanding of pointers. I know how to use pointers for basic things like call-by-reference and the like. I've been an iPhone programmer for about 5 years now so I understand how pointers are used for passing around objects and that sort of stuff. But, no, I'm not an expert on pointers in C. Edit: If you have any good articles/tutorials I'll gladly read them.

Comment: It's not really article/tutorial area... it's textbook area. One of the reasons universities teach C is because it forces you to deal with this material which is abstracted away in most languages. Put it this way: if Greg didn't show you how you should declare the original sentence (with a `char *foo[]`) are you sure you would've come up with it? How long would it have taken you? How about the `malloc()` call? These single lines of code can take a student hours--but that's the point.

Comment: I don't know how long it would have taken me. That's why I asked for help. I didn't ask Greg to give me the answer. I asked for a clarification on something. Are you really that bothered by what I've done here? I'm trying to understand pointers to the best of my ability.

Comment: I realize you didn't ask Greg for a full answer, but he supplied one and I asked _him_ about it. I had a hard time trying to explain why I feel like you're missing the point but it's easier to talk about specific things. 1. You asked for how to allocate memory and he gave you a one-liner back. But you should really know what `malloc()` is doing in memory. 2. You said something like "so I don't duplicate words", but you need to realize that C doesn't copy strings over unless you use a function like `strcpy()` (i.e. assignment doesn't work).

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/17961/discussion-between-roliu-and-anthony-frizalone)

Answer (score 0):

You can consider char** sentence as vector of strings. You can use string functions such as strlen, e.g: strlen(sentence[0]) would give you the lenght of the first line. You can then go from the end to the beggining, starting from lenght - 1 towards 0. Don't forget to count the spaces in the way so you can decrement the words counter correctly. Remember that perhaps you find more than one space separing two words and you should consider that when decrementing the counter. Don't forget to put the '\0' at the end of the new string.

To copy to the new 'vector of strings' you should be carefull with malloc's and realloc's or... you can search for the longest line and allocate all lines with that size. Remember that when you print a string it will stop when you get the '\0' caracter despite the size of the vector.